Android "onNewIntent" method not being called when a new Intent is invoked
I am trying to integrate Google Assistant into my basic Flutter app. However, when I run the built-in App Intent, OPEN_APP_FEATURE, consecutively, the app ‘refreshes’ and loses its state.
My goal is to invoke two methods in my Flutter app: one that calls the getNext() method and one that calls the like() method. While this currently works, invoking either method more than once causes the app to refresh. I want the app to maintain its current state and information without refreshing, allowing me to invoke the methods infinite amount of times. I am currently using method channels to call the Flutter methods (like and getNext) successfully.
I read up about the activity launch mode and switched my launch mode to both singleTask and singleTop to no avail. Relevant Doc
I think it has something to do with onCreate() method in my activity being called every time I try to invoke the app action, but can't seem to find a way to bypass this and invoke my onNewIntent() method.
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  private val CHANNEL = "com.example.built_in_intents"



  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate called with intent: ${intent.action} and uses ${intent.data}")
    handleIntent(intent)
  }


  override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "DOES IT EVER REACHHH")
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    Log.d("MainActivity", "onNewIntent called with intent: ${intent.action} and uses ${intent.data}")
    handleIntent(intent)
  }

Here is my shortcuts.xml in which the app actions are defined including the shortcut that invokes the getNext method
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <capability android:name="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.example.built_in_intents"
            android:targetClass="com.example.built_in_intents.MainActivity">
            <parameter
                android:name="feature"
                android:key="feature"/>
        </intent>
    </capability>

    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="click_button"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/button_push"
        android:enabled="true">

        <capability-binding
            android:key="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="feature"
                android:value="Button"/>
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>

And my relevant activity section inside my AndroidManifest Folder
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="built_in_intents"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />



        </activity>

The only solutions I have found thusfar on the web involve flagging the intent to Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, but I do not understand how to do that in this scenario.
